# I get duplicate results with foreach

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, plugins, foreach

I have this foreach so I want the visitagent value received for each element to check if it exists in the database, well then in block_viste_agent I have the function that blocks the visitagent value, the problem is that when I am going to block user via a value by checkbox then if there are others it adds them to me again there is also a detail that with characters like numbers I don't get them duplicates it work good, so I have the user agent and if I want to block a new one and there are 3 user agents already blocked, then it comes back and duplicates the ones that are blocked only what are blocked the user agent that I checkbox doesn't duplicates, what is wrong with my code?

```php
foreach ($_POST['visitagent'] as $agent_id) {
    $checkagent = $wpdb->query(
        "SELECT * 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}lcl_user_agent
        WHERE user_agent = '$agent_id'"
    );

    if ($checkagent <= 0) {
        $this->block_viste_agent(absint($agent_id), true);
    }
}
```

I looked for this question but I don't know my code is diferrent
[Getting duplicated results in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209631/getting-duplicated-results-in-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code.

```
if ($checkagent <= 0) {
    $this->block_viste_agent(absint($agent_id), true);
}
```

this one

```
if (!$checkagent->rowCount()) {
    $this->block_viste_agent(absint($agent_id), true);
}
```

Comment: I get this error Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on int in